# The unit square has dimension two?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

> Show that the Lebesgue Covering Dimension of the unit square $I^2$ with $I=[0,1]$ is two.

I know that a compact subset of Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ has Lebesgue dimension at most $n$. So it suffices to show that $\dim I^2\geq 2$. I first demonstrate an open covering of order three.

Let $G=[0, 1/2)\cup(1/2, 1]$. Then if $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are the projection maps of $I^2$ onto $I$, consider the collection $\mathcal{A}=\{(0,1)^2, \pi_1^{-1}(G), \pi_2^{-1}(G)\}$. $\mathcal{A}$ is clearly an open covering and has order three.

Now let $\mathcal{B}$ be an open refinement of $\mathcal{A}$ that still covers $I^2$. I want to show that $\mathcal{B}$ also has order three. I know that $\mathcal{B}$ must contain three distinct elements since it is a cover of $I^2$, a refinement of $\mathcal{A}$, and each element of $\mathcal{A}$ has an element which the other two do not.

I know that $\mathcal{B}$ cannot have order one. If it did, and $U\in\mathcal{B}$ and $V$ were the union of the rest of the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ then $(U,V)$ would form a separation of $I^2$ contradicting its connectedness.

Now I'm stuck on showing that $\mathcal{B}$ cannot have order two. I know that $\mathcal{B}$ has a Lebesgue number $\delta$, but it hasn't helped much. I thought about projecting the elements of $\mathcal{B}$ onto $I$ which I know has dimension one, but this doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I've tried working with partitions of unity, but they also haven't lent any insight.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

At Mirko's suggestion, I tried a different beginning open covering with order three. I think I've simplified the problem somewhat, but I feel like the gap required to finish this proof is still left to be traversed.

Let's start with the open covering Mirko suggested: $$\mathcal{A}=\{[0,2/3)\times I, (1/3, 1]\times [0,2/3), (1/3,1]\times(1/3,1]\}$$
$\mathcal{A}$ clearly has order three. Now let $\mathcal{B}$ be an open refinement of $\mathcal{A}$ which still covers $I^2$. By similar reasoning as above, $\mathcal{B}$ cannot have order one since $I^2$ is connected. So we just need to show that $\mathcal{B}$ does not have order two. Suppose it did to (hopefully eventually) get a contradiction. Let $\mathcal{B}'$ denote the set of all subsets of $I^2$ which occur as a connected component of some element of $\mathcal{B}$. Since $I^2$ is locally connected, $\mathcal{B}'$ is still an open covering of $I^2$. Further, $\mathcal{B}'$ still refines $\mathcal{A}$ and also has order two (assuming that $\mathcal{B}$ does). Now since $I^2$ is compact $\mathcal{B}'$ contains a finite subcover $\mathcal{C}$ of $I^2$. We can assume that removing any one element from $\mathcal{C}$ results in a collection which does not cover $I^2$. $\mathcal{C}$ still refines $\mathcal{A}$ and has order two (assuming $\mathcal{B}$ does).

We now have a finite collection $\mathcal{C}$ consisting of connected open sets (hence also path-connected) refining $\mathcal{A}$ such that any subcollection of $\mathcal{C}$ is not a cover of $I^2$, which, overmore, supposedly has order two. If we can show this is impossible, we have found our contradiction.

If we let $\mathcal{A}=\{A_1, A_2, A_3\}$ (where the $A_i$ represent the respective sets already stated), then each element of $\mathcal{C}$ lies entirely in one of the $A_i$ (perhaps two of the $A_i$) since each element of $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is connected. From here I don't see what to try next.

Comment: I think your starting cover is a bit complicated. I would suggest a different starting cover, if that helps: $[0,2/3)\times[0,1]$, together with $(1/3,1]\times[0,2/3)$, and  $(1/3,1]\times(1/3,1]$,

Comment: proofs that the dimension of the plane is 2 may be roundabout. There are different definitions of dimension, ind, Ind, dim (the latter being the Lebesgue covering dimension considered in your question) ... a direct proof might not be easy. E.g. in Engelking's General topology book the proof goes through a sequence of lemmas, showing that dim = Ind (for the plane and some more general spaces), and then a proof is given that Ind$R^2\ge2$, based on the Brouwer's fixed point theorem. Proofs of the latter may be based on algebraic topology (winding number) or combinatorial topology (Sperner lamma).